# What is the purpose of the ropes tied on roofs?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

So every interactable object I've found in the game so far has had some purpose.  Ropes tied to anything means you can shoot it with a rope arrow and something will happen.  Shooting at one tied to doors will allow you to break them down.  Shooting at a hanging object (e.g., boxes, torches, etc.) will cause it to swing.  One tied to a large pillar means there's a mounting point nearby to create a rope bridge.

But I haven't found the purpose of ropes tied to roofs.

[image: one of the ropes]

Shooting it when standing on a suspended box doesn't cause you to swing (although it goes against all physics).  Shooting it from the ground does nothing as far as I can tell.

What do these things do for me if I shoot at it with a rope arrow?

Comment: That's something I noticed as well - judging from those wooden planks underneath them, they appear to be covering holes on the rooftops. You may be able to break them, revealing these holes so you can conveniently drop in from above, but you won't be able to do so until you acquire a piece of equipment much later in the game. In the meantime, just jump and dance around on top of them with the assurance that you won't fall through.

Comment: Fire and Napalm arrows are available future upgrades. Perhaps they will allow us to burn the building down?

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro You can't break them. I've tried everything. The tool you're referring to, explosive and napalm arrows, grenade launcher, nothing works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Once you reach a certain point in the game, you can freely travel around the campsites gathering any missed GPS caches, relics, documents, etc. In some of these areas, the Mountain Village specifically, there will be more enemies, as well as new, helpful objects appearing in your Survival Instincts.

More specifically, there are some grounding points for rope lines scattered about, generally with a direct line of sight on the roofs with the rope coils. You can fire a rope arrow into the roof, ground it to the pole, and enjoy some ease of travel around the once hard-to-travel Mountain Village.

Sadly, that seems to be the only use for those roofs. Minor, unnecessary rope-lines, and annoying golden glares in your Survival Instincts.

Comment: I didn't even notice or remember seeing that post up on the top floor. It seems rather pointless for those being there when that path is hardly needed (considering you have complete ground access once you get the shotgun).

Comment: some of the rope wraps you see are designed to be broken (sometimes with the winch), but will not break if pulled on from the "wrong" direction.