# How do you break the rope that is around the door?

Tags: tomb-raider-2013

In Tomb Raider, I have a little problem.  I haven't played this game in a while, and don't know all of the computer controls anymore.

In the game, there is a door I need to enter.  The only problem is, it's locked by a rope (around the door).

It looks like this:
[image]

And it looks like this from a distance:
[image]

How I can break the rope?

Comment: Related: [What is the purpose of the ropes tied on roofs?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/107747/4797)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the [Rope Arrow](http://www.ign.com/wikis/tomb-raider/Rope_Arrow) to open these doors.

There are certain doors that can only be opened with the upgraded version, the [Rope Ascender](http://www.ign.com/wikis/tomb-raider/Rope_Ascender).

Comment: Thank you for your quick responce, i will try it when i am home!